# 2 text fields clear when 1 clear button is pressed swift 3

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have 2 text fields in the same view controller. I have added the "Clear Text Always Visible" option for both text fields in the storyboard. For some reason when I click the clear button for the second text field, both text fields clear. I cant find any information on this problem on the internet and am not sure how to fix it. Thank you for your help.

Here is a screen shot of the outlets, both are connected correctly and I have declared them as the delegates, the first text field has a tag of 0 and the second has a tag of 1

[image: outlets]

Comment: Maybe you've added the same action to both textFields

Comment: well I added them through the storyboard so I believe they are added to only their specific instances. Only the second one behaves this way, clearing the first one only clears the first text field

Comment: Add screenShot of storyboard outlets

Comment: added, I am not sure if this is what you wanted but in the storyboard there doesnt seem to be any cross outlets or anything labeled incorrectly, all calls to each corresponding delegate work correctly